# Confusion regarding the definition of limit

Tags: limits

> We know that, $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$$is equivalent to the following statement, $$(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\ge n_0)(\left\lvert x_n-x\right\rvert<\varepsilon)$$

But my question is that if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ is interpreted informally we can say that the limit of $x_n$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$ is $x$ and this is equivalent to saying, $$n\to\infty\implies x_n\to x$$From this perspective, it seems that we need to define the symbols $n\to\infty$ and $x_n\to x$ separately but one of my friend said that it is redundant, and it is of course evident from the standard definition. But I think that it is necessary from this viewpoint. Where am I wrong?

---

**Added:-**

I think that the wording of the original question has created some confusion about the focus of it. So, I will try to elaborate this point a bit. Thinking that a large part of Mathematics can be phrased to be "formalization of intuition" I asked the question.

We are told that informally $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ means that,

> $x_n$ tends to $x$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

So, I thought that it is natural to formalize this intuitive statement.

As a first step, we note that the above written statement is equivalent to the following statement,

> $x_n$ tends to $x$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$.

The second step is,

> $n$ tends to $\infty$ implies $x_n$ tends to $x$.

So, I thought that if we can formalize the word "tends to" we will be finished. For this I took help of the symbol $\to$ and formalized the above statement as,

> $n\to \infty \implies x_n \to x$

But this said formalization will be nonsense if we can't express the meaning of $n\to\infty$ and $x_n\to\infty$ formally and it can be done easily by [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence). So, the conclusion of all these was that, $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x\iff (n\to \infty \implies x_n \to x)$$but in the same page (the link of which is provided above) we find that, $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x\iff x_n \to x$$I **insist** that my confusion is ***not*** at all regarding the symbols but their logical (or formal) interpretation which apparently leads to the nonsensical equivalence, $$(n\to \infty \implies x_n \to x)\iff x_n \to x$$

In **Mauro Allegranza**'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211175/confusion-regarding-the-definition-of-limit/1211371#1211371) it is said that 'nowhere we have the concept of "something approaching to something other" '. True. Note that, we also did't need this concept in appointing the symbol $\to$ while formalizing our statement.

Comment: Indeed you are not defining $n \to \infty$ or $x_n\to x$. You are defining "$n \to \infty \Rightarrow x_n \to x$", and the definition is the one you give.

Comment: @John: But I thought (please correct me if I am wrong) that to be able to "define" a statement $P\implies Q$, the statements $P$ and $Q$ should both be well-defined.

Comment: Might be I shouldn't use your notation. Think it this way, when you say $x_n \to x$, it is a bit vague: what is actually moving such that $x_n$ moves to $x$? So $x_n \to x$ alone don't make a lot of sense. You have to state something like "$x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$".

Comment: @John: I knew that this answer would come. But what about if we say that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ is logically equivalent to $x_n\to x$ then it doesn't remain vague at all.

Comment: Then $n \to \infty \Rightarrow x_n \to x$ is not the same thing as $x_n \to x$ (whatever the definition of $n \to \infty$ is).

Comment: @John: Exactly. And there is my confusion. Also see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence).

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you trying to come up with an alternative definition of a limit?

Comment: Actually,, $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$$is equivalent to the statement: $$(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\ge n_0)(\left\lvert x_n-x\right\rvert<\varepsilon),$$ not to the statement in the question.

Comment: @Did: Can you precisely tell me the reason?

Comment: @JackM: Is it clear now?

Comment: Since $x$ appears in the assertion $\lim x_n=x$, the second assertion cannot start with $(\exists x\in\mathbb R)$. Note that the second assertion in your post is equivalent to $$(\exists y\in\mathbb{R})(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\ge n_0)(\left\lvert x_n-y\right\rvert<\varepsilon)$$ Would you say that this proposition is equivalent to  $\lim x_n=x$?

Comment: @Did: You are right. I missed your point. Edited.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I cannot add nothing more ... The "part" ${n\to\infty}$ is already "embedded" into the *sequence* notation $(x_n)$, that we can write more fully as $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$. Is the concept of sequence that conveys the notion of "never ending" list of real numbers. If we agree on this and on the possibility of "handling" this infinite set as a "single entity" then - under certain circumstances - we can associate to it a **single** number : **the** limit of the sequence, more or less in the same way as we can associate to the "population" of the U.S. the U.S. President.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Yes you are right. In some sense the "part" $n\to\infty$ is redundant, at least in this case. But redundancy isn't something that is of importance in this case because it leads us to the equivalence of $P\implies Q$ and $Q$, which is absurd.

Comment: *[sees title]* Ah, you are not the first…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not defining **two** concepts, but **only one** :

> **the** *limit* of a sequence.

A sequence of *real* numbers : $(x_n)$ is a *function* :

> $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$

i.e. $f(n)=x_n$.

The [Limit of the sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence) $(x_n)$, if it exists, is a number $L$ such that :

> > For each real number $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that, for every natural number $n \ge N$, we have $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$.

Thus, we have two "objects" : *sequence* and *limit of a sequence*, where the first one is defined independently from the second one.

This is the "formal" translation of the intuitive concept of "a sequence of numbers approaching to a limit".

The symbol :

> $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$$

is the traditional way to denote "the limit of the sequence" $(x_n)$ and, in spite of its "typographical complexity", it is only one symbol.

We can more simply omit the $n\to\infty$ part, which is redundant, being already "included" into the definition of *sequence* as an infinite list of real numbers, and write : $L=lim(x_n)$ in place of $x_n \to L$ and its definition will be :

> > $$L=lim(x_n) \ \ \iff \ \ \forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists N \in \mathbb N \ \forall n \ge N \ \ |x_n - L| < \epsilon.$$

You can see the details in :

- Stephen Abbott, [Understanding Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=JXvBBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA38) (2000), page 38-on.

  ---

We have to note that the bi-conditional :

> $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x\iff (n\to \infty \implies x_n \to x)$$

will not do as definition of *limit*.

If we consider a *finite* sequence : $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$, we have that $n\to \infty$ does not hold and thus the conditional : $(n\to \infty \implies x_n \to x)$ is satisfied for an $x$ whatever.

This means that we are licensed to call an $x$ whatever "the limit" of the above sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much for the added portion.

Answer (score 0):

The symbolism "$x_{n} \to x$ as $n \to \infty$" reads "$x_{n}$ gets closer to $x$ as $n$ gets larger". But, to state precisely what we mean by saying that is an entirely different matter.

What is interesting here is that the sense of mathematical preciseness is NOT a pedantic one, so you would never see any mathematician insists on assigning to every symbol a "one-to-one" definition. A significant example is of course the sign $dx$ in an integral. Its meaning varies from context to context. So does the symbol $\infty$.

The essential point is that when one scribbles then he knows exactly what he is doing. If you take a look at some older texts, then you would find that some authors write $\lim_{n = \infty}$ freely. No harm was committed, heartedly.

A major purpose of a mathematical symbol may be mnemonic, suggestive, and convenient for a given goal. Note that in a poem, which is also a capsule of thoughts, the same word may have a different meaning at a different place. Mathematical symbols, to me, play the same role.

There seems no need to make symbols "logical", for insisting on that leads one to nowhere. 
For example, I do not see any virtual effect on differentiating "$= o(1)$" from "$\in o(1)$" for those who know exactly what they mean by writing the former...

Comment: My friend also said a variant of the same feeling that there '...seems no need to make symbols "logical"' but when I told this to other friends, they told me that though they think that sometimes being emphatic about logic is redundant, they think that every mathematical symbol should have a definition in terms of existing mathematical symbols. For example, we need to define the symbol $\displaystyle\sum$ in terms of, say $+$ and $\cdot$ simply because it is not one of the primitive symbols of our number system.

Comment: I would say that concepts themselves are what really matter in mathematics. And, yes, mathematics defines new concepts in terms of older  concepts! Symbols themselves are auxiliary.

Comment: Whatever you want  to write for the concept of convergence of a sequence, everybody eventually refers to the $\epsilon$-definition, rather than what you write.

Comment: Actually my question was regarding the seemingly obvious paradox of the logical interpretation of $n\to\infty\implies x_n\to\infty$ and $x_n\to\infty$ which are not equivalent as @John said. But we assume that they are equivalent.

Comment: Please recall that $\infty$ is not a number if we are talking about the real numbers. We cannot operate with $\infty$!

Comment: Yes you are right. We can't operate with $\infty$ if we are talking about real numbers. But the nature of $\infty$ is immaterial here. We can deal with $n\to\infty$ even if $\infty$ is not a number. To be precise, the logical equivalent of $n\to\infty$ may be given as $(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})(\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N})(n_0>n)$.

Comment: There is nothing sophiscated here. Just think that we give the long epsilon definition a suggestive name, which is exactly "$x_{n} \to x$ as $n \to \infty.$"

Comment: Note also that when doing analysis manually, feeling is always the director, rather than logic. Logic helps check the intuition. Do not be played by logic. To quote N. Bohr, "No, you are not thinking, you are just being logical"...

Comment: You could either view the $\infty$ in $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ as a "shorthand" or a "mnemonic"… or, you could think of it as an actual infinity. The standard definition isn't the only possible definition, and there are other equivalent definitions that use an actual infinity (such as the hyperreals). Sometimes it's convenient to think of it as an actual infinity.